# Restricting download limit in Squid

Tags: squid

I wanted to restrict the download limit in the Squid proxy so I added the following two lines in the squid.conf.

acl officelan dst 192.168.1.0/24

reply_body_max_size 30000000 deny officelan

Now, I want to allow some/particular IP to download more than 30MB limitation so I included another acl as alowedip and included the following lines but this is not working.

acl allowedip dst 192.168.1.81

reply_body_max_size 0 allow allowedip

How do I allow acl allowedip to have unlimited download ?

Warm Regards

Supratik

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Squid checks for matches in the order they are written in the conf file from top to bottom.

Make sure that the

```
reply_body_max_size 0 allow allowedip
```

is before the

```
reply_body_max_size 30000000 allow officelan
```

If you're using a new (>v3) version of squid then there is no need for the allow and deny e.g.

```
reply_body_max_size 0 allowedip
reply_body_max_size 30000000 officelan
```

EDIT

Tested using centos 5.5 and squid 2.6.STABLE21 2 machines on the same network as the proxy. Here's the relevant entries from my squid.conf

```
acl t1 src 192.168.254.200
acl t2 src 192.168.254.0/24

http_access allow t1
http_access allow t2

reply_body_max_size 0 allow t1
reply_body_max_size 100000 allow t2
```

This works as expected - reducing the byte size in the second statement (and restarting squid) eventually causes squid to refuse the transfer.

Comment: My Squid version is

squid-2.6.STABLE21-6.el5

Running under CentOS release 5.4 

I used the following order but not luck.

reply_body_max_size 0 allow allowedip
reply_body_max_size 30000000 deny officelan

Comment: Then use your original statements and ensure the allow is before the deny.

Comment: I just checked the documentation properly and the `deny` should be `allow` too.

Comment: I tried as you suggested, now my configuration looks the following
acl allowedip dst 192.168.1.81
acl officelan dst 192.168.1.0/24

reply_body_max_size 0 allow allowedip
reply_body_max_size 30000000 allow officelan

but still able  to download a large file more than 30MB from all IP's. 
Only one statement is working at a time.

Any idea ?

Comment: I've just had an opportunity to test this and it works as expected. See the edit to my answer for the statements I used.

Answer (score 0):

Just re-order your reply_body_max_size lines. Squid check them in order.

This is from squid config file:

```
When the reply headers are received,
the reply_body_max_size lines are processed, and the first line with
a result of "allow" is used as the maximum body size for this reply.
```